# Can't change my brightness

Tags: screen, brightness

I just bought my Asus Zenbook UM425IA with a r7 4700U Everything was okay until i started installing Ubuntu where the first errors start appearing. First i got ACPI BIOS ERROR and then after i installed it, i couldn´t change my brightness or anything related to my screen. I tried installing third parties controllers but even those didn´t seem to work and then i checked that i only had acpi_video0 and my files inside where all on 49, i dont know if that is related or not. It seems like nothing related to my amd cpu and gpu works

Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: Are you really using Ubuntu? In your recently [deleted question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1288646/816190), you [initially](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1288646/1) mentioned elementaryOS. Users here would help you considering you're using Ubuntu which may be useless for elementaryOS.